# How to scrape just the post content in linkedin containing email id in R?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I have been trying to scrape post contents from linkedin based on keyword search. With the help of stackoverflow community, I was able to manipulate URL and search linkedin for the keywords with my R script. But now, after scrolling say 10 times, I want to scrape only those posts which contains an email id in an anchor tag. This is how the html appears in linkedin if there is an anchor tag associated within the post :

[image]

I am unable determine how to write the xpath so that I can scrape both the span containing the normal text as well as the anchor tag at the same time. This is what I have been trying :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(xml2)



try(rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = 'firefox'))
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.linkedin.com/login")

user <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"username")
user$sendKeysToElement(list("xxxx",key="tab"))

pass <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"password")
pass$sendKeysToElement(list("xxxx",key="enter"))

ex<-c("jobs in delhi","jobs in mumbai","jobs in bangalore","how to get a job in india")
for(b in 1:4){
  urls[b] = paste0("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/content/?keywords=",ex[b],"&origin=CLUSTER_EXPANSION")
}

j<-1
a1<-vector()
final<-vector()
for (b in 1:4) {


  remDr$navigate(urls[b])

  for(i in 1:10){
    remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
    Sys.sleep(5)    
  }
  page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()

  a1 <- xml2::read_html(page_source[[1]]) %>% try(html_nodes(xpath="//a[contains(text(), '@')]/parent::span/parent::div[@class, 'feed-shared-text__text-view feed-shared-text-view white-space-pre-wrap break-words ember-view']"))%>% html_text()
  p1 <- length(a1)

  if(p1!=0){
    for(k in 1:p1){
      final[j]<-a1[k]
      j<-j+1
    }
  }

  }
```

Note that I have given the user id and pass as "XXXX". Would be grateful if someone can help me out with the proper xpath query.

Comment: Please provide a sample url where a post contains an email id. I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

This should select the posts you want :

```
//div[@class='feed-shared-text__text-view feed-shared-text-view white-space-pre-wrap break-words ember-view'][.//a[contains(.,"@")]]
```

To get the text of each post easily, I think you can go with :

```
string((//div[@class='feed-shared-text__text-view feed-shared-text-view white-space-pre-wrap break-words ember-view'][.//a[contains(.,"@")]])[1])
```

**EDIT :**

or

```
(//div[@class="feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper ember-view"][.//a[contains(.,"@")]])[1]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

where [1] is the value to increment (from 1 to the total number of posts you get)

To extract the text of a post displayed on a single page :

```
string(//div[@class="feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper ember-view"][.//a[contains(.,"@")]])
```

**EDIT 2 :** To extract the text of posts displayed on a search result page :

```
(//div[@class="feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper ember-view"][.//a[contains(.,"@")]])[i]/div[1]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

or

```
string((//div[@class="feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper ember-view"][.//a[contains(.,"@")]])[i]/div[1])
```

where [i] is the value to increment (from 1 to the total number of posts respecting your "email condition")

Comment: Hey @E.Wiest did you run the code you sent? What output did you get? Because I am getting similar output as my code, and its not working exactly. Useless information from the website is being scraped.

Comment: As I told you in the comments, I wasn't able to find a webpage where post contains email id. Please provide me one. I've worked with this url https://www.linkedin.com/company/excella-consulting/ imagining posts could contain email id. This XPath expression : `string((//div[@class='feed-shared-text__text-view feed-shared-text-view white-space-pre-wrap break-words ember-view'])[1])` will output the text of the first post. If I have to correct the XPath expression, please provide url or hmtl code (no image) I can work with.

Comment: Here's one such post. 

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/themanishanegi_hiring-recruitment-jobs-activity-6661118743445405698-WQsH

Comment: The XPath works. I've edited my answer with an alternative and one new XPath expression for post displayed on a single page. `//div[@class='feed-shared-text__text-view feed-shared-text-view white-space-pre-wrap break-words ember-view'][.//a[contains(.,"@")]]
` selects correctly posts containing an email address (tested OK with https://www.linkedin.com/in/themanishanegi/detail/recent-activity/shares/). Are you dealing with a list of results or single pages? I'm not sure to undestand what do you expect as output : the text of posts containing an email address or just the email address ?

Comment: So, with every keyword search, i am scrolling down say 10 times, and i want to scrape all the posts that appear in that scroll containing an email id

Comment: I've edited my answer. `//div[@class="feed-shared-update-v2__description-wrapper ember-view"][.//a[contains(.,"@")]]` is the selector you need. For example, with : https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/content/?keywords=HR%20Operations&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL, if you scroll and apply the previous XPath expression, you'll get posts containing an email address.